# How do I display a custom accessibility toolbar in a WordPress menu based on new position options?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am currently workin on a  WordPress extension, named [One Click Accessibility](https://github.com/pojome/one-click-accessibility). This extension provide a toolbar that add  accessibility options such as font resizing, grayscale, negative contrast, etc..

I would like too add two new positional options for the toolbar toggle icon: `menu-left` and `menu-right`.

I have successfully added these two new positional but the thing is, I’m kinda stuck. Even though I’ve added the two positions I'm not quite sure what my next steps should be to make everything work smoothly.

Now the 2 positions are available in the wp appearance/customize/accesibility section/ but they doesnt do anything :
[with pos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4awYb.png)
[no pos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCf4w.png)

Here is what i did :
In the *pojo-a11y-customizer.php* i've added two lines in the field :

**Before :**

```php
$fields[] = array(
    'id' => 'a11y_toolbar_position',
    'title' => __( 'Toolbar Position', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => array(
        'left' => __( 'Left', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
        'right' => __( 'Right', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
    ),
    'std' => is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left',
    'description' => __( 'Set Toolbar Position', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
);
```

**After :**

```php
$fields[] = array(
    'id' => 'a11y_toolbar_position',
    'title' => __( 'Toolbar Position', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
    'type' => 'select',
    'choices' => array(
        'left' => __( 'Left', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
        'right' => __( 'Right', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
        'menu-left' => __( 'Menu Left', 'pojo-accessibility' ), //New option to add toolbar in the menu to the left
        'menu-right' => __( 'Menu Right', 'pojo-accessibility' ), // Same but for the right
    ),
    'std' => is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left',
    'description' => __( 'Set Toolbar Position', 'pojo-accessibility' ),
);
```

And in the *pojo-a11y-frontend.php* fil i've added this :

**Before :**

```php
        $toolbar_position = $customizer_options['a11y_toolbar_position'];
        if ( empty( $toolbar_position ) || ! in_array( $toolbar_position, array( 'right', 'left' ) ) ) {
            $toolbar_position = 'left';
        }
```

**After :**

```php
        $toolbar_position = $customizer_options['a11y_toolbar_position'];
        if (empty($toolbar_position) || !in_array($toolbar_position, array('right', 'left', 'menu-left', 'menu-right'))) {
          $toolbar_position = 'left';
        }
```

No what will I have to do to make those two positions work ? Do you have any idea ?

Comment: You'll have to "translate" that value you got in `$toolbar_position` into styling now somehow. Ideally, IMHO, you would add a class on the body element (using the `body_class` hook), and then let your theme's stylesheet do the rest based on that.